# Allow bash script to run commands on multiple processors

Tags: parallelism, cpu-usage, multiprocessor

I have a script `compute_all_matrices.sh` which launches deepTools' `computeMatrix` for a whole bunch of different files with various option. The user manual for `computeMatrix` states:

> `--numberOfProcessors INT, -p INT`
>
> Number of processors to use. Type "max/2" to use half the maximum number of processors or "max" to use all available processors. (default: 1)

I'd like to use up to 8 processors for each one, one after the other, and there are other people using these processors so I can't take them all. However, when I check on `htop`, it looks like the script `compute_all_matrices.sh` is only using one processor.

Is there any way to allow the "superscript" to use multiple processors for its "subscripts"?

**EDIT**

I am usure why, but apparently my superscript was using all of the processors, just not all of the time. I think I must have only checked the state of CPU usage when it was using only 1 processor. Is this possible? If so, I believe that this question can be closed.

Comment: have you tried  `-p 2` ? 
perhaps a snippet of the invocation of computeMatrix would help.

Comment: @D'ArcyNader I don't see why `-p 2` would change anything, there are 24 total available, and right now it's just me using them. What do you mean by a snippet of its invocation?

Comment: The _script_ would only ever run on a single CPU. What does `htop` tell you about your `computeMatrix` job?

Comment: @Kusalananda This may have been what confused me. I'm pretty sure `computeMatrix` was running on just one processor when I checked, but it may have been just for one phase of it, or it could have been that I was in fact `compute_all_matrices.sh` that was running on just the one.